# Teradata as webapp backend?

Tags: database, web-applications, teradata, client-side

Does anyone have experience using Teradata as the backend for a typical, responsive client-side web application? What were your experiences? I'm wondering if Teradata meets performance requirements to serve modern webapps, and how difficult or easy it is to use for that purpose.

Comment: Short answer is yes, it certainly can serve as the backend for a web app. But you need to be sure your db is well designed, you have good workload management rules in Teradata, etc.

Comment: Have you used it for that purpose? How responsive was it?

Comment: I have. As long as your workload management t is appropriately configured to prioritize "tactical queries" and you pay attention to your queries to try to make them single amp, or two amp or few amp operations you can get hundreds of queries per second using a pool of sessions. You need to pay attention to primary indexes, unique secondary indexes, join indexes and so on. Generally NUSI's are not helpful unless there is relatively high level or uniqueness but in some cases they can help.

Answer (score 0):

We have a very large data Analytics application that builds huge datasets (tens of millions of rows/day/table) in Teradata.  Some of the calculations are based on entries from the User Interface (a Java, Java Script, Angular application). Additionally, many of the visualizations for the UI were controlled by UI entries in tables.

We considered the challenge of putting the UI database on an OLTP and attempting to keep the data in sync between the OLTP and Teradata and chose instead to put the full UI database on Teradata.

We have had more than adequate response for the UI on Teradata.  Please keep the following things in mind:
1. number of users.
2. number of tables.
3. number of transactions.
4. size of transactions.

We had a very small user base, and low transaction volume from the users.  Any impacts of using an OLAP as an OLTP database are so small that our users are not feeling the impact.

Also, we did limit the amount of integrity checking defined at the database level.  We depend upon the UI to be a good actor and NOT insert duplicate rows.

We have other applications with thousands of users and I would never put them on Teradata.  OLTP databases serve that purpose well and that is where those applications should house their data.